# NSFileManager moveItemAtPath issue

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager

I am using NSFileManager to move items from one file path to another file path but it results in an exception.But i dont get exception every time, the exception is raised only after second or third time of loading the urls

> Exception Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x631a900
>   {NSUserStringVariant=Move, NSFilePath=/Users/cgvak/Library/Application
>   Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.3/Applications/3731EEFB-03F8-4E0B-BF5D-A94BEE0D2DE2/Library/Caches/imgcache//loading/http:__www.sankar.com.au_sankar_property_photo_2010_09_30_dc4a35f82ee70002604f6c06fd811f9d_m.jpg,
>   NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/cgvak/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/4.3/Applications/3731EEFB-03F8-4E0B-BF5D-A94BEE0D2DE2/Library/Caches/imgcache//ready/http:__www.sankar.com.au_sankar_property_photo_2010_09_30_dc4a35f82ee70002604f6c06fd811f9d_m.jpg}

What should i do in order to overcome from this problem?Please any body help me to overcome from this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you checked that the path exists? also there is an // in the file path. Try to remove that one.

Could you also post you code, with out code we really have to guess.

The `Cocoa error 4` means that you are trying to move a file that does not exist, this could also mean that the target directory does not exists.

Answer (score 2):

Please Check **`NSSearchPathDirectory`**

**Instead**

```
NSArray * paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

**Write This**

```
NSArray * paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```