# Move file failed after URLSession didFinishDownloadingToURL

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am running on the simulator, and I get this error:

> file:///Users/hunterp/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/asd3243423-A1A4-4CFB-8A8F-234asdasd/data/Containers/Data/Application/4564561we-5FC5-4718-843B-sdasdwq4134/tmp/CFNetworkDownload_o0xtzV.tmp
>   Moved failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa
>   error 4.)

and I do:

```
    var test = DownloadClass(url: s, completionBlock: { (location) -> () in
        println (location)
        var toPath = self.getDocPath().stringByAppendingPathComponent("s.jpg")
        self.moveFile(location.absoluteString!, toThePath: toPath )
        println ("DONE")
    })
    test.start()
```

WHERE:

```
   func moveFile(fromPath: String, toThePath: String) {

        var error: NSError?
        let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

        if filemgr.moveItemAtPath(fromPath, toPath: toThePath, error: &error) {
            println("Move successful")
        } else {
            println("Moved failed with error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    func getDocPath() -> String {
        return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    }

class DownloadClass: NSObject,NSURLSessionDelegate,NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    var session:NSURLSession?
    var downloadUrl:String
    var completion:(NSURL)->()
    init(url:String,completionBlock:(location:NSURL)->()){
        completion = completionBlock
        downloadUrl = url
        super.init()
        session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(), delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }
    func start(){
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: downloadUrl)!);
        let downloadTask = session!.downloadTaskWithRequest(request)
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
        completion(location)
    }
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        //here get progress
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895078/nsfilemanager-moveitematpath-issue

Comment: location.absoluteString! change to location.path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change move path code to this,it will work

```
self.moveFile(location.path!, toThePath: toPath )
```

Comment: I did not see that.You comment 15 seconds before me

Comment: @hunterp you should pass the downloadTask.response?.suggestedFilename to save the file with the correct name